# A nice riley, hopefully is fun

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Within these lines is a puzzle I've made.
With cunning and wit, can you guess my trade?

Inside the tome of the element's power,
One minute per side, you'll read for an hour.

A single number of the Croupier's spin
Is purest of gold, at this depth you'll win.

The answer is here I give you my foot!
From heel to arch is where it's been put.

Comment: If this is a Riley Riddle the [[tag:affix-riddle]] tag may apply

Comment: Are we looking for a single word here, with each (possibly overlapping) part building a part of that word? Or is this a regular riddle?